# Stationary, Martingale difference sequence, Ergodic process

Tags: martingales, ergodic-theory, stationary-processes

Does the sequence $\{x _{t}\}_{t=1}^{n}$ satisfy the following conditions if it is generated from a normal distribution with a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 3?

*Stationary? Yes, because the sequence's first and second moments are finite.

*Martingale difference sequence? Yes, because the time series' expectation is zero.

*Ergodic process?

My question is how do I demonstrate that the sequence is ergodic?

Comment: Do you imply that $x_t$ are independent?

Comment: It's not enough for stationarity to have finite moments. The reasoning about the martingale difference is also wrong.

Comment: Yes, $x_t$ are independent.